# ssh: connect to host ec2-65-098-002-001.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a .pem file for the Linux instance and still I am unable to connect to the instance. What could be the issue?

ssh: connect to host ec2-65-098-002-001.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: Connection timed out implies there's a firewall blocking the port.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.